# django query: how to find lessons followed by lesson with same parameters using model query API

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have following model of a lesson and I would like to find every lesson that is preceded or followed (less than 15 minutes) by lesson with the same language, room and teacher

```
class Lesson(models.Model):
      room = models.ForeignKey(Room, null=True, blank = True)
      language = models.ForeignKey(Lnaguage)
      teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, null=True, blank = True)
      start = models.TimeField()
      end = models.TimeField()
      date = models.DateField()
```

Is this possible using django's model query APIs? If yes, how can I find these lessons?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `Q` which allows you to create queries with `AND` and `OR`

Consider you have a lesson data at hand,

```
lesson = Lesson.objects.get(id=......)
```

than

```
from django.db.models. import Q
from datetime import timedelta

filtered_lessons = Lesson.objects.filter( (Q(start__lt=lesson.end+timedelta(minutes=15)) | Q(end__gt=lesson.start-timedelta(minutes=15)))) # define time criteria using OR

filtered_lessons.filter(date=lesson.date, room=lesson.room, teacher=lesson.teacher, language=lesson.language) #apply the other filters
```

Of course, you can use sfingle statement as joining the two queries. Also you can use `&` like

```
filtered_lessons = Lesson.objects.filter( Q(Q(start__lt=lesson.end+timedelta(minutes=15)) | Q(end__gt=lesson.start-timedelta(minutes=15))) & Q(teaher=lesson.teacher) &Q(....) & Q(....))
```

[Here is the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for complex lookup parameters...

Comment: the problem is that i don't want to find neighbors for a specific lesson as you are doing, because i want to get every lesson that satisfies these conditions. Using your method I'll need to cycle through every lesson, i.e. compare every lesson witch each other in a for cycle

Comment: What you want is not possible, because for checking what you want, you *have to* make comparison, and you can not compare unless you choose a specific item...